# easiest way to draw 2D crystal structures

Tags: drawing

This might be an easy one but anyway, I am trying to find a software to be able to draw simple 2D crystal cells like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure#Lattice_systems). With latex tikz package it takes too much time. I also tried Google SketchUp as well but as  it is a 3D software I couldn't figure out aan easy way to do it. Is there any simple way?

Comment: Why don't you use the svg files from your link? Wikipedia provides them, just click on them.

Comment: Thanks. I think Inkscape is better than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

These structures are three-dimensional, I suppose it is way easier to use some 3D way to create them, their representation on a screen is always 2D. Suppose you want to show them on the web (you didn't mention the media), you could take a look at three.js for example, with that you can define the single points (vertices) and connect them with lines.

Comment: I want to use the image in a report. I think Inkscape as a freeware is better for me.